# mongoose update into an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema

```
var ArticleSchema = new Schema({
user_id: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
title: String,
description: String,
content: String,
visible: Boolean,
saved: Boolean,
deleted: {type: Boolean, default: false },
permalink: String,
created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
edited_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
tags : [],
comments: {
    comment: String,
    name: String,
    email: String,
    date: Date,
    deleted: Boolean,

}
```

});

I want to update the deleted field into the comments array for a specific array.

Here is how I'm doing it.

```
    this.model.update(
{
    _id: data.articleId
},
{
    $set: { 'comments.$.deleted' : true }
},
function(err, doc){
    console.info(doc);
    console.info(err);
    callback(doc);
});
```

};

Nothing happens, I tried directly on mongo console and it works.

But not in mongoose. For any reason I got in console.info(), null and 0 as results. The document is never updated.

If I try to update other value not nested it works.

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following:

```
this.model.update(
    {
        _id: data.articleId
    },
    {
        $set: { 'comments.deleted' : true }
    },
    function(err, doc){
        console.info(doc);
        console.info(err);
        callback(doc);
    });
};
```

Your code is not working because the comments field is not an array but an embedded sub-document and the [**`$`** **positional operator**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) only identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array.

Comment: @chriam yes you had part of the reason of my problem, i was using a embeddded document, not an array. So i changed the mongoose schema to fit it... thanks....